net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED website displayed but data not received
i use nodejs reactjs express mariadb, when i launch my web app and trying to access it from another machine in my local network the web app is displayed normally but data not received from the database, so many parts in website that need database not appear and have error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
i try to : disable UFW _ change bind-address to 0.0.0.0 _ create new mariadb user with grant access to all remote IP addresses

Are the web app and the database server on the same network?  Is there, perhaps, a router in the way?

yes in the same network
